# Calculating c and n sub naught in Big-O Analysis

Tags: performance, time, big-o

The great people at MyCodeSchool.com have [this introductory video on YouTube](http://youtu.be/OpebHLAf99Y?list=PL2_aWCzGMAwI9HK8YPVBjElbLbI3ufctn), covering the basics of Big-O, Theta, and Omega notation.

The following definition of Big-O notation is provided:

`O(g(n) ) := { f(n) : f(n) ≤ cg(n) }`, for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

My casual understanding of the equation is as follows:

Given a function `f()`, which takes as its input `n`, there exists another function `g()`, whose output is always greater than or equal to the output of `f()`--given two conditions:

- `g()` is multiplied by some constant `c`
- `n` is greater than some lower bound n<sub>0</sub>

Is my understanding correct?

Furthermore, the following specific example was provided to illustrate Big-O:

Given:

- f(n) = 5n<sup>2</sup> + 2n + 1

Because all of the following are true:

- 5n<sup>2</sup> > 2n<sup>2</sup>, for all `n`
- 5n<sup>2</sup> > 1n<sup>2</sup>, for all `n`

It follows that:

- c = 5 + 2 + 1 = 8

Therefore, the video concludes, f(n) ≤ 8n<sup>2</sup> for all `n ≥ 1`, and g(n) = 8n<sup>2</sup>

I think maybe the video concluded that n<sub>0</sub> must be `1`, because `1` is the only positive root of the equality 8n<sup>2</sup> = 5n<sup>2</sup> + 2n + 1 ( Negative one-third is also a root, but n is limited to whole numbers. So, no dice there. )

Is this the standard way of computing n<sub>0</sub> for Big-O notation?

- Take the largest powered factor in your polynomial
- Multiply it by the sum of the coefficients in your time function
- Set their product equal to your time function
- Solve for zero
- Reject all roots that are not in the set of whole numbers

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct, but from your wording - "I think maybe the video concluded that n<sub>0</sub> **must** be 1", I have to point out that it is also valid to take *n<sub>0</sub>* to be 2, or 3 etc. In fact, any number greater than 1 will satisfy the required condition, there are actually *infinitely* many choices for the pair *(c, n<sub>0</sub>)*!

The important point to note is that the *values* of the constant *c* and *n<sub>0</sub>* does not really matter, all we care is the *existence a pair of constants (c, n<sub>0</sub>)*.

#### The Basics

Big-O notation describes the *asymptotic behavior* of a given function *f*, it essential describes the *upper bound* of *f* when the its input value is *sufficiently large*.

Formally, we say that *f* is big-O of another function *g*, i.e. `f(x) = O(g(x))`, if there exists a **positive** constant *c* and a constant *n<sub>0</sub>* such that the following inequality holds:
*f(n) ≤ c g(n)*, for all *n* ≥ *n<sub>0</sub>*

Note that the inequality captures the idea of *upper bound*: *f* is upper-bounded by a *positive* multiple of *g*. Moreover, the "for all" condition satisfies that the upper bound holds when the input *n* is sufficiently large (e.g. larger than *n<sub>0</sub>*).

#### How to Pick *(c, n<sub>0</sub>)*?

In order to prove *f(x) = O(g(x))* for given functions *f, g*, all we need is to pick *any* pair of *(c, n<sub>0</sub>)* such that the inequality holds, and then we are done!

There is no *standard* way of finding *(c, n<sub>0</sub>)*, just use whatever mathematical tools you find helpful. For example, you may fix *n<sub>0</sub>*, and then find *c* by using Calculus to compute the maximum value of *f(x) / g(x)* in  the interval [*n<sub>0</sub>*, +∞).

In your case, it appears that you are trying to prove that a *polynomial* of degree *d* is big-O of *x<sup>d</sup>*, the proof of the following lemma gives *a* way to pick *(c, n<sub>0</sub>)*:

#### Lemma

If *f* is a polynomial of degree *d*, then *f(x) = O(x<sup>d</sup>)*.

> Proof: We have *f(x) = a<sub>d</sub> x<sup>d</sup> + a<sub>d-1</sub> x<sup>d-1</sup> + ... + a<sub>1</sub> x + a<sub>0</sub>*, for each coefficient a<sub>i</sub>, we have a<sub>i</sub> ≤ |a<sub>i</sub>| (absolute value of a<sub>i</sub>).
>
> Take c = (|a<sub>d</sub>| + |a<sub>d-1</sub>| + ... + |a<sub>1</sub>| + |a<sub>0</sub>|) , and n<sub>0</sub> = 1, then we have:
>
> *f(x) = a<sub>d</sub> x<sup>d</sup> + a<sub>d-1</sub> x<sup>d-1</sup> + ... + a<sub>1</sub> x + a<sub>0</sub>*
>
> ≤ *|a<sub>d</sub>| x<sup>d</sup> + |a<sub>d-1</sub>| x<sup>d-1</sup> + ... + |a<sub>1</sub>| x + |a<sub>0</sub>|*
>
> ≤ *(|a<sub>d</sub>| + |a<sub>d-1</sub>| + ... + |a<sub>1</sub>| + |a<sub>0</sub>|) x<sup>d</sup>*
>
> = *c x<sup>d</sup>*, for all x ≥ 1
>
> Therefore we have *f(x) = O(x<sup>d</sup>)*

Comment: Thank you!

So, say we have an f() that is monotonically increasing, like our f() above. We can set c wherever we want, but doing so will affect the point where f() and g() intersect. Because we are dealing with a set of n restricted to whole numbers, and ostensibly we don't care about data sets of size zero, it is _prudent_ to choose a c where n naught is at least 1, but not _mathematically necessary_?

Comment: Also, what's this deal with `ai < |ai|`? Is this saying, "Sometimes a sub i is less than zero; sometimes it's not. But when it is, it's less than the absolute value of a sub i"?

Comment: @LMiz You are right, the value of *c* will general have effect on the value of *n0*. Moreover, choosing a *c* where *n0* is at least 1 is not mathematically necessary. In fact, sometimes it is *impossible* to find a *c* such that *f(1) ≤ c g(1)* (for example, consider *f(x) = x, g(x) = x - 1*, we certainly have *f(x) = O(g(x))* in this case). On the other hand, *c* cannot be whatever we want, consider the case *f(x) = 2x, g(x) = x*, clearly *c = 1* will not work in this case.

Comment: You are right regarding the absolute value. Note that it is *essential* to take the absolute values. This will ensure that *c > 0* in the proof, which is required by the definition. (Multiplying by a negative number will alter the sign of the function, and hence will not give an upper bound)

Comment: I see: with less than or equal to in the lemma, the proof totally makes sense.

Cool!

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I wonder if there are some words I can Google to learn more about how mathematics handles problems like these--finding functions that will always serve as upper and lower bounds for a given function on subsets of the function's domain. Asymptotic Analysis? Something like that?

Comment: **Practice makes perfect**, this applies especially in Maths, where you really need to get your hands dirty in order to truly understanding how things work. So I strongly recommend you to start with doing some [big-o exercises](https://www.google.com.hk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=syXwU5WhIcqL8QeswID4DA#q=big-o+exercises).

Comment: Will be digging into these shortly. :) Thank you!